# OpenGL Depth Buffer not using z value

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, depth-buffer, qtopengl

I have a QtOpenglWidget with OpenGL 3.3 running and attempting to do instance rendering, but my z-buffer will not work

Currently, I add the 3 test cubes in draw order of cube3, cube2, then cube1 and changing it shows it is just displaying the last cube drawn. I also know `DEPTH_TEST` is enabled as messing with `glDepthFunc` will just not show anything.

[image]

My init:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

My Draw:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Vertex:

```
layout(location = 0) in highp vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in highp mat4 modelToWorld;
uniform mat4 MVP;
out highp float DEPTH;

void main() {
    gl_Position = MVP * modelToWorld * vec4(position, 1.0);
    DEPTH = gl_Position.z / 20.0f;
}
```

Frag:

```
in highp float DEPTH;
out highp vec4 fColor;
void main() {
   fColor = vec4(DEPTH, DEPTH, DEPTH,1.0);
}
```

**EDIT**
I am finding out this might be a QtWidget issue, The first thing being called in `main` is

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setVersion(3, 3);
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

Comment: Do you even _have_ a Z-Buffer? Just enabling the depth test is not enough - the depth test will do nothing if the currently bound framebuffer has no depth buffer.

Comment: @derhass sorry to sound dumb, but I was under impression z-buffer == depth test, also why would `glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER)` remove everything then?

Comment: @FrickeFresh: well, I just wanted to make you aware that you can't automatically assume that the depth buffer is there (I don't know if Qt has some default formats settings which would enforce that). It is correct that if no depth buffer exists, setting `GL_GREATER` should have no effect.  Another possibility is that you just project everything to the same plane. You might think that you ruled that out by visualizing `gl_Position.z`, but actually, the z value the depth test will use is derived from `gl_Position.z / gl_Position.w`, and you might have constructed such a projection matrix.

Comment: Apart from `gl_Position.z / gl_Position.w` being constant, I could imagine the hypothetical case that you set a `glDepthRange` which maps everything to a single value, but that is really very hypothetical and would be more or less breaking the depth test on purpose, so I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @derhass I think you hit it with the `gl_Position.z / gl_Position.w` as doing that all the cubes are white regardless, I am gonna try fudging around with my MVP again

Comment: Well, you could include your actual matrices in the question. My suspicion would be that the third row of the matrix conceptually looks like `(0 0 a 0)` and the fourth row like `(0 0 b 0)`, which completely divides the depth away by projecting everything to `z_ndc=a/b`. But you could also use other means to acheive the same effect, i.e. in the model or view matrices.

Answer (score 2):

After **HOURS** of debugging and referencing examples, I found the issue!

It was this line

```
void MyWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height) {
    ...
    m_projection.perspective(45.0f, width / float(height), 0.0f, 1000.0f);
    ...
}
```

it should be

```
void MyWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height) {
    ...
    m_projection.perspective(45.0f, width / float(height), 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    ...
}
```

Apparently setting my projection with a nearPlane to 0 causes this. I actually don't know **WHY** this occurs so please enlighten me in comments if you know

Note: this is the [QMatrix4x4](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qmatrix4x4.html#perspective) class

Comment: I don't know what `QMatrix4x4` exactly does when specifying a near plane distance of 0.0, but a perspective projection with that property doesn't even exist in terms of how projective transformations are applied in a rendering pipeline - the resulting view volume would have to be infinite in NDC space, which completely contradicts the _definition_ of the view volume to be a well-defined axis-aligned cuboid in NDC space.